# How to add antd radio button for react?

Tags: reactjs, redux, radio-button, antd

I'm importing *Radio* from *antd* in my project.

I need two radio buttons named "Taxable" and "Non Taxable".

```js
import {Button, Radio, Form, Icon, Input, message,Modal,createFormField,Row,Col} from "antd";

<Row gutter={24}>
    <Col span={24}>
    <FormItem>
        {getFieldDecorator('IsTaxable', {
        initialValue: "",
        rules: [{
        required: true, message: 'Please Choose your option!',
        }],
        })(
        <Radio value='true'>Taxable</Radio>


        )}

    </FormItem>

    </Col>
</Row>
```

How do I include the second radio button  so that I can view these radio buttons in two columns(two lines)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Vertical RadioGroup](https://ant.design/components/radio/#components-radio-demo-radiogroup-more) or you can also use `<br/>` tag as well.

You can check here with working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/how-to-add-antd-radio-button-for-react) demo.

*Code Snippet with style*

```js
const radioStyle = {
    display: 'block',
    height: '30px',
    lineHeight: '30px',
};

<FormItem>
    {getFieldDecorator('IsTaxable', {
    initialValue: "",
    rules: [{
    required: true,
    message: 'Please Choose your option!',
    }],
    })(<RadioGroup onChange={this.onChange}>
        <Radio style={radioStyle} value={true}>Taxable</Radio>
        <Radio style={radioStyle} value={false}>Non Taxable</Radio>
    </RadioGroup>
    )}

</FormItem>
```

*Code Snippet with `<br>` tag*

```html
<FormItem>
    {getFieldDecorator('IsTaxable', {
    initialValue: "",
    rules: [{
    required: true,
    message: 'Please Choose your option!',
    }],
    })(<RadioGroup onChange={this.onChange}>
        <Radio value={true}>Taxable</Radio> <br />
        <Radio value={false}>Non Taxable</Radio>
    </RadioGroup>
    )}

</FormItem>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to custom style the `radio buttons` Similar to vertical radio group demo here - https://ant.design/components/radio/

https://codesandbox.io/s/rj2692803o

```
 const radioStyle = {
   display: "block",
   "margin-bottom": "5px",
   "border-radius": "3px"
 };

<Radio.Group defaultValue="taxable" buttonStyle="solid">
   <Radio.Button value="taxable" style={radioStyle}>
     Taxable
   </Radio.Button>
   <Radio.Button value="non-taxable" style={radioStyle}>
      Non-Taxable
   </Radio.Button>
</Radio.Group>
```

[image]